# Is there an event firing when Chrome shuts down?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It seems like `chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener` doesn't fire when Chrome shuts down. Is there a way to track a Chrome shutdown event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to detect browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event)

[Chrome extension action on shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501062/chrome-extension-action-on-shutdown)

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that your extension will be able to handle an event, see [Chrome extension action on shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501062/chrome-extension-action-on-shutdown)

Answer (score 0):

Two of the most popular events of HTML DOM that are used to detect browser's close event are `onunload` and `onbeforeunload`. Using `onunload` is pretty straight forward, just subscribe the JavaScript event. `onunload` works okay on Internet Explorer, but doesn't work fine in Mozilla Firefox. On the other hand, `onbeforeunload` works okay on IE,Firefox and chrome, so using `onbeforeunload` is safe.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onbeforeunload = WindowCloseHanlder;
function WindowCloseHanlder()
{   
window.alert('My Window is closing');
}
</script>
```